# Adjusting Linux Group Access

Tags: linux, rhel5

I have created a group in RHEL with one user in it. This user will need full rwx access to /home/anotheruser/ ,recusively. How do I change the user/group permission to allow that user/group to rwx in /home/anotheruser/

If I do a vi group in /etc/ this is what is says:

```
usergroup:x:505:user123
```

Also, what is the :505: mean?

Thank you for any input!

Answer (score 2):

505 is the group ID.

You need to put the both users in one group and make the /home/anotheruser/ can be writable by group:

```
usermod -a -G usergroup anotheruser
chmod -R g+w /home/anotheruser/
```

Change `umask` to 0002 so newly created folder will has permission 775.

```
echo "umask 0002" > /home/anotheruser/.bashrc
```

Set SGID bit for all folders in `/home/anotheruser/` to make all folders created by `user1` will be owned by `usergroup` group:

```
find /home/usergroup -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod g+s /home/usergroup
```

Comment: Great, before I execute these commands... do I have to be in root? Any specific place as to where I should execute them? Can this mess up my files or permissions in the /anotheruser/ directory?

Comment: @mcfan123 - Yes to being root and the potential to mess stuff up. No to needing to be in a specific directory when you run those commands.  You seem unfamiliar with Unix permissions concepts.  I suggest reading up on them before taking any action to make sure you don't create unintended nasty surprises.  http://www.zzee.com/solutions/unix-permissions.shtml is a good starting point.

Comment: will the umask 0002 change all umasks?

Comment: my current bash setup is if [ $UID -gt 99 ] && [ "`id -gn`" = "`id -un`" ]; then
        umask 002
else
        umask 022
fi

Comment: it means that if uid is greater than 99 and effective user ID and effective group ID is the same, set umask to 002.

Comment: both umasks should be 002 in bashrc?

Comment: Do you want `anotheruser` can write to the folder that created by `user`?

Comment: I want user123 to be able to write in anotheruser

Comment: Do it for only `anotheruser` user.

Comment: This may seems silly to ask but, what am I do to exactly?

Comment: Exactly what? I think you should **really** understand what you do.